# Are Access Point (AP) and Master Mode the same thing?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

Is Access Point mode and Master mode the same thing? Looking at the manual it seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual mode is referred to as Master mode. Devices that are capable of Master mode are commonly referred to as Access Points. Because of this, there is some intermixing of the names.

References

[hak5](https://hak5.org/episodes/haktip-9)
[ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode)